# Unit of costmap created by r.walk

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, cost-path

I created a cost map from an elevation map an a (degree) slope map using r.walk (version released on 2015-03-12) in QGIS 2.14.3. According to the documentation the resulting map should display the time needed to reach each raster cell from my starting point. As far as I understood, the unit of time should be seconds. I wanted to mask the area reachable in 3600 seconds, but it is only about 800 m wide on more or less flat terrain.

Could the unit of time be something else than seconds? Or is there some other error in my thinking.

Comment: It is seconds. You have to provide more information about the inputs. What is your friction for example (use r.univar) and the other parameters.

Comment: @Anna Inputs where a ASTER DEM with approximately 25 m resolution. I derived a slope map with r.slope.aspect with default settings. I run r.walk with default settings as well.

Comment: You don't need slope map. You provide elevation raster and friction raster. Friction raster can be raster map of zero for start (such as r.mapcalc "friction = 0"), please read the manual page to understand the inputs.

Comment: You can actually use a slope map as an approximation of friction, if you don't have anything better. However the output depends heavily on the lambda-value (default 1.0). For my data a very small lambda-value (0.02) produced results, that where (based on own walking experience in the area), quite realistic.

Comment: The slope along the path is computed within the module from the provided elevation. It is possible to provide slope map as friction, but that is steepest slope, and I think it makes sense only in very specific cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you used a geographic projection, so the cells are not square, so the units are not going to make sense. The only way this works is to use a UTM raster with square cells. With a flat UTM raster, I got the expected result in seconds. I got better results with r.walk.coordinate (though r.walk.points should work fine in theory).

It's important to include a friction raster (don't use the DEM here, or your costs will be multiplied by the cell's elevation). If you only want slope to affect travel cost, the friction raster should have 0 values in all cells (as Anna points out, no need for a slope map; you can also make one in the raster calculator).

Finally, the default coefficients follow Langmuir's quite unrealistic rule of thumb for hiking times (who hikes at 12 km/h?). I use the following coefficients, which approximate real life, data-based hiking times (for example, [Irmischer and Clarke 2017](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15230406.2017.1292150) and [Márquez et al. 2017](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00167223.2017.1316212)); it reaches a top speed of 4.5 km/h for 0° to -5° slopes. (in the attached image that compares curves, this curve is labelled GRASS. The vertical axis is km/h and x-axis is slope in degrees].

Coefficients: 0.8,5.0,-3.25,-5.5

Slope_factor for 18°: -0.3249

Knight's move: checked

(note that at a distance of 4.5 km, travel times should be 1 hour [3600 seconds], but in fact vary from 0.99 hours to 1.03 hours. Even with the knight's move checked, travel times are not perfect circles on a flat DEM).

r.walk has aged well (written in 2002!), but it's ultimately limited since alternate formulas can't be inputted. The most useful thing moving forward would be a QGIS plugin implementation of [Albert's movecost R package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/movecost/versions/0.5), which includes a number of recent cost formulas. ([here's video tutorial for movecost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Iv-eyiSUCk)).

Hope this helps,
Erik

[image]

Comment: Actually during the last 3 years I have figured it out myself, but your answer is a very good summary of the solution and hints to a useful new tool. Thanks.