# Finding easiest path to walk on topographic map?

Tags: qgis, topography, shortest-path

I want to make the shortest path between two points, but the thing is that there's a hill in the middle. I used Naismith's rule to calculate how the slope interfers in the walking time and I did the math for this work. I have the DTM, grid and points.

It's something like the shortest path problem I want to solve:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

I don't know how to get the lines "height" (tallest vertex height minus lowest vertex height).

[image]

Comment: For the lines "height", are you after the "height" of a segment between 2 adjacent vertices or the "height" of an entire path?

Comment: Could you describe the structure of the data of your line network and the points? Does each point have a unique ID, and those IDs are found in the lines as well?

Comment: The lines "height" I'm talking about is the difference between the vertices heights, not the altitude of the line itself. Line AB have a height of height of point A minus height of point B. I want this measure to understand how steep is this line.

Every point and every line segment are unique entities.

Answer (score 1):

The tool you're looking for is GRASS' [r.walk](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.walk.html), which uses a raster DTM to create a cost surface. R.walk calculates higher travel times over stepper slopes and accounts for distances between pixels (no need to build this grid or estimate slopes manually, as you've done with your vertexes). Once you have a cost surface, [r.drain](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.drain.html) will connect points back to the origin point, creating a least cost path. I wouldn't recommend using Naismith's curve, which is unrealistically fast; see [this post on r.walk and comparisons between least cost curves.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244514/unit-of-costmap-created-by-r-walk)
–Erik